Visual Studio2022のGoogle Testにおいてクラスのテストを効率良く書く方法について（リンカーの設定）
C++の初心者です。
Google testでテストを書くにあたって、クラスを用いるテストは以下の参考URLの記載を参考にしました。
「構成プロパティ -> リンカー -> 入力 -> 追加の依存ファイル」に参照するオブジェクトを追記する方法をとっています。
参考URL：
テスト対象のオブジェクトの参照の追加 | Visual StudioのGoogle Testプロジェクトの使い方 その1
この方法だと次の点が気になっています。

テスト対象のプロジェクトで新しくクラスを追加する度にテストプロジェクトの「構成プロパティ -> リンカー -> 入力 -> 追加の依存ファイル」からオブジェクトファイルを指定して追加必要があり、あまり効率的ではない。
テストするcppをインクルードする方法でも動くことを確認しているが、あまり推奨されている方法ではないと感じている。個人的にはこの方法で二重インクルードが防げるのかわからない。また参考URLにあるようにヘッダーファイルによる参照関係が複雑化した場合に管理が複雑になりそうである。

実際に大規模なプロジェクトにかかわっている方は、参照オブジェクトファイルを手動で追加するような運用はしていない気がするのですが、オブジェクトの範囲指定や自動参照などで効率化する方法はないのでしょうか。
試したこと

参照するオブジェクトそのものではなく、オブジェクトが格納されるファイルのパスを指定した。（ファイル名のないオブジェクトファイル（例：.obj）を参照しようとして参照エラーとなった）
ワイルドカードで「..*/obj」と指定した。（参照エラーにはならずビルドは通ったが、テストエクスプローラーにテストが出てこないためテストが実行できない。）

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Visual Studio で C++ DLL 用の単体テストを作成するで説明されていますが、「構成プロパティ -> リンカー -> 入力 -> 追加の依存ファイル」を使う方法が適切な選択肢なようです。そのため、

ワイルドカードで「..*/obj」と指定した。（参照エラーにはならずビルドは通ったが、テストエクスプローラーにテストが出てこないためテストが実行できない。）

この方法でビルドエラーが発生していないのであれば問題ありません。「テストエクスプローラーにテストが出てこない」は別原因の可能性があります。まずはVisual Studioを使わず、ビルドされた実行ファイルを実行し、テストが意図通りに作成され、テストできているかを確認、問題を切り分けてください。

意図通りに作成できていない場合
→ 面倒でもまずは個別にobjファイルを列挙し、どのファイルを参照すべきか、どのファイルは参照していけないのか、更に切り分けてください。その上で、「..*/obj」ではなくどのような書き方にすべきか、という観点に質問文を書き換えてください。
意図通りに作成できている場合
→ 本件は解決済みとし、新たな質問スレッドで「テストエクスプローラーにテストが出てこない」件を尋ねてください。


回答ありがとうございます。
切り分けを行ったところ、次の結果となりました。
「構成プロパティ -> リンカー -> 入力 -> 追加の依存ファイル」
の設定方法
①列挙する方法（例：$(SolutionDir)TargetProject$(Platform)$(Configuration)\sample1.obj;sample2.obj）
→ビルドにも成功し、テストエクスプローラーにテストが表示されました。コマンドプロンプトからテストのexeファイルを実行したところテスト結果が表示されました。
②ワイルドカードによる指定（例:$(SolutionDir)TargetProject$(Platform)$(Configuration)*.obj）
→ビルドは成功しましたがテストエクスプローラーには何も表示されませんでした。コマンドプロンプトからテストのexeファイルを実行しても、テスト対象のプロジェクトのmain関数と同じ出力結果が表示されました。①と比較するとテストの実行結果ではないためテストプロジェクトとしては作成できていないと結論づけました。
結果を踏まえ「構成プロパティ -> リンカー -> 入力 -> 追加の依存ファイル」によるファイルの指定はワイルドカードの指定には対応しておらず、列挙する形で追記していくしかない、となるでしょうか。

@shibaast ここは質問文を書く場所ではありません。
